# Cで横ならびに数を入力、表示したい

Tags: c

Cで横並びに数を入力、表示したいです。
「標準出力に半角数字でaとbの値の大きい方を出力してください。aとbが同じ値の場合は半角小文字アルファベットで「eq」と出力してください」という問題です。

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d", &a); scanf("%d", &b);

    if(a == b)
        printf("eql");
    else if(a > b)
        printf("%d\n", a);
    else if(b > a)
        printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

上記のように書きました。
数を入力するときにscanf()やgets()を使うと勝手に改行されてしまいます。
改行をせずに表示するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 「scanf()やgets()」 を使っても「勝手に改行されてしまいます」ということはないと思います。どのようなコードを書いているのか追加して下さい。なお、`gets`は既に廃止されている関数ですので、使用するべきではありません。

Comment: 12を入力したら、enterキーを押さずとも(スペースキーを押したらとか?)24が表示されて欲しいという事でしょうか?
そうであれば、ncursesというライブラリを使うとよいかもしれません。

Comment: @BLUEPIXYさん、@MIURA Yasuyukiさん
ご指摘ありがとうございます。質問を改善しました。

Comment: a,b どちらでもいいので期待する出力例を書いた方が良いです。

Comment: つまり入力行と**同じ行**に出力したいということですか？

Comment: 入力を（手で打ってるなら） Enter じゃなくて CTRL-d で終えるとかです?

Comment: 解決しました。勘違いでした。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);`で横並びに入力できます。

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int a=0;
    int b=0;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    if(a > b){
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }else if(b > a){
        printf("%d\n", b);
    }else{
        printf("eq\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

実行時はスペース区切りで入力します。

```
$ a.aut
12 24
24
```

実行結果：http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/t9VvsGcPwSImrKeL

Comment: 質問にあるコードでもスペース区切でできますよ。

Comment: @myoga あれ･･･？そうなんですか？すみません元のコードは未確認でした。。だからみなさん意図を汲み取りかねているのですね･･･

Answer (score 1):

お使いの端末上で以下を実行してみて下さい。

```
$ stty -icanon min 1 time 0
```

その上で当該コマンドを実行します。

```
$ ./a.out
10 10 eql  # <= "10 10" と入力した後、スペースを入力すると判定結果が同じ行に出力されます
```

とは言うものの、stty コマンド等で端末制御が可能な環境でのみ有効な方法ですので、Windows OS で cmd.exe をお使いの場合には当てはまらないと思います。まぁ、ご参考程度にどうぞ。

Comment: スペースを入力する事によって入力を終了したいのでしたら、tty を弄らなくても、main の先頭で `setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` するだけで良いと思うのですが。

Comment: すみません…勘違いでした。自分の試した環境では既に `stty -icanon` になっていたようで、何もしなくてもスペースで判定結果が出ただけのようでした。お騒がせしました